# jquery dialog not displaying correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am using jquery dialog.  The dialog is displayed correctly in IE11 -- it has border, title bar, etc, but it is not displayed correctly in Chrome version 40, no border, no title bar, only the title, text and buttons, and it even doesn't cover the page underneath it, the modal:true is also not working in Chrome. No errors shown in the Chrome page.   Any help will be appreciated.

The JSP code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- version 1.11.x -->

function showDialog()
{
  $("#dialog").dialog(
  { 
   height: 200,
   width: 350,
   closeOnEscape: false,                    
   modal: true, 
   dialogClass: 'no-close success-dialog',
   buttons:
   {                        
      "Yes": function()
      { 
          $(this).dialog( "close" );                    
      },
      "No": function()
      {
          $(this).dialog( "close" );                
      }
   }
});
}
```

Comment: is code inside a *document.ready* handler? Are any errors thrown in page?

Comment: no, it is not.  This part of code will be called when a button is clicked, then the dialog (this code) will be shown.  This code is inside a            function showDialog().  No errors shown in the page... Thanks

Comment: Try to update Chrome, here we had serious issues with v40, in jQuery and CSS.

Comment: Isn't v40 the most recent version of Chrome ?